# Windows Phone 8 Fast App Resuming: The 'ActivationPolicy' attribute is not declared

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Any project that I try on my computer will give this error in VS2012 when I try to compile after adding the attribute for fast app resume in WMAppManifest.xml: "The 'ActivationPolicy attribute is not declared'.

I've tried 3 different Windows Phone 8 projects, including a sample from Microsoft. They all give the error when I try to compile. It's adding this attribute that breaks it: `ActivationPolicy="Resume"`
to this line:
`<DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="MainPage.xaml" />`

I've repaired my WP8 installation.

Comment: With these projects you are targetting WP8.0 and not 7.1, correct?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, very sorry for posting this. I found my own solution.

I just completely uninstalled then re-installed the Windows Phone 8 SDK. (Repairing it didn't work)

Comment: @SimzzDev Answering your own questions is desirable in SO and it's a good thing - in fact you can even see that your solution helped the guy above me.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason you would get this is because you have an old wp7 project that hasn't been upgraded to WP8.

Answer (score 0):

Check the file YamanoteCommonTypes.xsd in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Xml\Schemas

In that file, cut & paste the following xml defitions over the existing ones:

```
<xs:simpleType name="ST_ActivationPolicyThirdParty">
<xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>
    The activation policy of a 3rd party task
    </xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="Resume"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Replace"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

and

```
<xs:complexType name="CT_ThirdPartyExtendedAppTask">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>
    Represents an entry point container
</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="BackgroundServiceAgent" type="CT_BackgroundServiceAgent" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
<!-- These attributes will only be parsed if the runtimetype is ST_RuntimeType::ModernNative -->
<xs:attribute name="ImagePath" type="y:ST_String" use="optional" />
<xs:attribute name="ImageParams" type="y:ST_String" use="optional" />
</xs:complexType>
```